# Return decoded String from base64-encoded ByteArrayOutputStream

Tags: java, base64, bytearrayoutputstream

I use `DeflaterOutputStream` and `ByteArrayOutputStream` for my test.

```java
String a = "Hello world";
byte[] bArr = a.getBytes();

ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(bArr.length);
DeflaterOutputStream deflaterOutputStream = new DeflaterOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream);

deflaterOutputStream.write(bArr);
deflaterOutputStream.close();

bArr = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

System.out.println("out: "+Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bArr));
```

As a result, I get this Base64 string:

> eJzzSM3JyVcozy/KSQEAGKsEPQ==

How can I get "Hello world" again from this Base64 string?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Comment: If there's an `encodeToString` method, there's probably a `decodeFromString` or similar method too?

Comment: Be careful when using `getBytes()` without the `Charset` argument as the platforms default charset will be used instead, which might be unintentionally.

Comment: knittl, encodeToString - it's just converting the byte array to base64. If u use decodeformString then u will get byte array ByteArrayOutputStream type, but not string "Hello World".

Comment: Take the string and shove it through the reverse process of what you shoved the original through. i.e. decode the Base64 to a `byte[]`, wrap in a `ByteArrayInputStream` what that in a `InflaterInputStream` read the result of all that into yet another `byte[]` then wrap that in a `String` with platform default encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the way back from your Base64 string you need to "inflate" the compressed content like this:

```
    String base64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bArr); // eJzzSM3JyVcozy/KSQEAGKsEPQ==

    // reverse
    byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64);
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream2 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    InflaterOutputStream inflaterOutputStream = new InflaterOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream2);
    inflaterOutputStream.write(decodedBytes);
    inflaterOutputStream.close();
    System.out.println("out: "+ byteArrayOutputStream2.toString()); // Hello World
    byteArrayOutputStream2.close();
```

Comment: A well-designed Java API works back and forth .. so for `getEncoder().encode(..)` there is the reverse `getDecoder().decode(..)`. See [Java Base64 Tutorial: Decode](https://www.base64decoder.io/java/)